# Window size in LSTM: training and testing

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am reading papers on how LSTM is used for regression in time-series. During training, the dataset is split in fixed-size chunks that depend on the window size. The window slides over the training data, and these small sequences are fed into the network. 
For testing, I would expect the test set to be split likewise in fixed-size sequences, but I read that this is not necessary and often the whole sequence is fed into the network for inference. 
**Questions** 
How does this work? What do authors mean with "the whole sequence"? Is the input for the LSTM during the test phase completely independent on the window-size used during training?